# Any tips on understanding Stable matching and unstable pairs

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, computer-science-theory

[image]

I thought i understood stable matching but am really confused with pairs, can anybody help me understand this simply?

Answer (score 0):

Let's quickly remember **Gale-Shapley** Algorithm:

---

- 1. One of the two sets is chosen to make proposals.

  - `S` selects from `H`.

---

- 2. One individual from the proposing group who is not already selected `H` will propose to their most preferable option.

  - **Hospital**

  ---

  - **Accept:** If it is the hospital's first offer or the `S` is at better ranking than their current `S` ranking.

    - For instance: If Whittington's(`W`) current is Ahmed(`A`) and Laura(`L`) proposes for `W`. `L` replaced with `À`
  - **Reject:** `S` ranking is worse than their current `S` ranking.

    - For instance: If Whittington's(`W`) current is Ahmed(`A`) and Elena(`E`) proposes for `W`. `E` is rejected.
- 3. When each member of the set is matched, loops terminate.

So:

---

Laura(`L`) selects Royal Free(`R`)

Elena(`E`) selects St. Thomas(`T`)

Ahmad(`A`) selects Whittington(`W`)

Simon(`S`) selects HighGate(`H`) ok.

- If Elena(`E`) selects Royal Free(`R`), this will create an unstable pair. Since `E` is accepted. According to the `R`, `E` has a higher rank compared to the `L`.
- If Simon(`S`) selects Whittington(`W`), he will be rejected. Since his rank is the lowest according to the `W`.
- If Ahmad(`A`) selects St. Thomas(`T`), he will be rejected. The highest rank of the `H` is `E`.
- If Elena(`E`) selects HighGate(`H`), she will be rejected. Since her rank is the lowest according to the `H`.

---

For [Gale-Shapley Algorithm](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0m_YW1zVs-Q)

---

For [Unstable-pairs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RE5PmdGNgj0)